# como quitar la hora de la fecha en java?

Tags: java, time

Tengo una variable de tipo Date llamada fechaElab
y la utilizo en el value de un p:Calendar de primefaces

```html
<p:calendar id="mask"  pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" mask="true" locale="es" value="#{Registro.datosVO.fechaElab}"
```

Entonces al seleccionar cualquier fecha, me marca lo siguiente
PROBANDO FECH AWed Feb 14 00:00:00 CST 2018
y siempre marca la misma hora,entonces lo que quiero es quitar la hora
como le puedo hacer?

Comment: Ya intentaste con calendar.date calendar.year??

Answer (score 1):

En tu base de datos el campo debe ser de tipo **date()** probablemente lo tienes como un **timestamp with time zone**, en este caso aun que le des formato a la fecha siempre te pondrá el tiempo en ceros 00:00:00, y si ya no puedes cambiar el tipo de dato en la base de datos entonces cuando  recuperes la fecha le puedes hacer un **SimpleDateFormat** por ejemplo:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class FormateDate {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String date_s = "2011-02-19 00:00:00.0";

        SimpleDateFormat dt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
        Date date = dt.parse(date_s);

        SimpleDateFormat dt1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        System.out.println(dt1.format(date));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para que solo te guarde la **fecha** tienes que hacer lo siguente:

- fechaElab tiene que ser `Date()` en java
- fechaElab tiene que estar **mapeada** como Date
- en la base de datos `Date` no `datetime`  "esto depende de que base de datos estes usando"

Answer (score 0):

Un `java.util.Date` representa los milisegundos que han pasado desde una fecha llamada epoch (01/01/1970 00:00:00 GMT).

Por lo tanto, milisegundos es su precisión. Va a depender de tu motor de base de datos el tipo exacto de almacenamiento y con que precisión date, datetime, datetime con timezone.

Si lo que quieres es visualizar esa fecha sin los detalles de tiempo, entonces tienes que especificar un formato de visualización, con `SimpleDateFormat` por ejemplo.